# Next line matching the regex in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file in the format:

```
Port Number
IP address
Port Number
IP address
```

(Not sure how the output will be displayed here but let me tell you they are on separate lines)

and so on....

I use the command `grep -C 1 'port number' file.txt`
i.e. I want all IP addresses corresponding to a particular port. Making it simple, I want the next line matching a regular expression. Like if my regular expression matches line 2,4 and 6 then I want lines 3, 5 and 7 to be printed. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

use awk. Its simpler to understand than sed.

```
awk '/port number/{getline;print }' file
```

`'getline'` gets the next line after `/port number/` is matched.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -n '/^port$/{n;p}' < file.txt`

`-n` tells sed not to print the input text as it processes it.  You want this since you only want to see the lines which match your criteria.

`/^port$/` restricts which lines `{n;p}` will operate on to those matching the specified port.

In `{n;p}`, the `n` means to read the next line of input into sed's pattern space.  This will be the line that contains your IP address.  The `p` then tells sed to print its pattern space, so the IP address line is printed.

Comment: This deletes all the lines containing the 'port number' regex.

Comment: It doesn't delete anything.  It reads `file.txt` and for every line that matches `/^port$/` prints the next line, just like you asked.

Comment: No, your regex is too restrictive. Your `sed` command is likely to not print anything at all based on the OP's example data.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
sed -n '/Port Number/{n;p}' file.txt
```

In GNU `sed` case insensitive:

```
sed -n '/Port Number/I{n;p}' file.txt
```

Comment: Is n the number of lines to display? And what is p?

Comment: `n` is the `sed` command to read the next line. `p` is the `sed` command to print the line (since `-n` tells it not to print lines by default).

Comment: There should be a semicolon after p, like so: `sed -n '/Port Number/{n;p;}' file.txt`

Comment: @MaxGillett: Some versions of `sed` may require it, but GNU `sed` doesn't.